# Is HTML 5 good enough for developers to switch from Flash?

Tags: html5, flash

Just curious, because many developers use Flash to do many things that HTML 4 (correct me if I'm wrong) or below cannot or had a hard time doing, like for example the rounded corners (Canvass) and that Video Thing and many more.

I have not actually explored all of HTML5, so might as well learn it from you.

thanks.

Comment: Keep using Flash if you don't care about your site visitors enough. (Like me... >:D)

Comment: Countless questions like this have been asked. The answer is that right now you can use some parts from html5 like the new input types which will degrade in older browsers. HTML5 will never be a complete replacement for flash.

Comment: @muntoo, ahm care of what?  Taking ages to load the page?
@Keyo, oh, ok..

Comment: The question is not one of good enough, you need something standardized and vendor neutral. Sorry about sounding like Steve Jobs but I swear I am typing this on a WinXP.

Comment: @Pa Poy - what @muntoo is saying is that some people won't or can't use a Flash plugin.

Comment: @Fanatic23.. ahm would you kindly explain a bit... and yes so am i, on WinXP.
@ Stephen C, oh ok.

Comment: @Fanatic23 - if you're typing that on WinXP then you definitely *don't* sound like Steve Jobs!

Comment: @glenatron Actually, Steve Jobs secretly has a whole collection of Windows computers down in his basement. For some reason, he spends about 5 hours a day there. I wonder why...

Comment: @muntoo lol..... maybe get some ideas from thus windows computers...

Comment: @muntoo Heh - they must be great for when he gets tired of staring at a spinning beachball.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rounded corners and stuff like this is not what flash is meant for, and these applications will die off very soon as more advanced CSS and HTML 5 kicks in. Where Flash really has advantage now is applications with very rich GUI, non-trivial user interaction (drawing, messing around with many different elements in various ways, rich maps, etc.). Now, you could probably make most of these things in HTML 5, but since Flash has tools, libraries, widgets, experienced developers and so on, it would take time until the same is developer for HTML 5. So if you're starting the project right now you may have better luck with Flash (if you task indeed requires the power of Flash - if you just need video/some CSS, go HTML 5), but that might change in a couple of years.

Comment: But what about iOS devices? How are those guys managing without the "powers" of Flash?

Comment: @dotslash you're looking at the 5 years old answer. That's what I meant when I said "might change in a couple of years". HTML5 has made much progress since 2010.

Comment: @StasM LOL, never realized that. Does that mean HTML5 has surpassed Flash now? If not, is the iOS community cut off from Flash apps?

Comment: @dotslash I would say yes, now there are rich and powerful frameworks available for building very complex applications, including effects, graphs, widgets, and there are much more developers that are comfortable with it. So I would say yes, HTML 5 now overcame Flash and there's no point to do new development on Flash anymore.

Answer (score 2):

While it is too early to say about near future, ultimately I think I think it is HTML5 which will be the new standard, I base this hunch on the fact most of the trend-setter like Apple, Google, MS are either making HTML5 their main area of thrust or alternatively making it one of their priorities. Which is why I think we will have mature, stable and fast platform for HTML5.

Comment: oh yeah, i found 1 video in YouTube, MS hosted a seminar/Talk about HTML5 and SVG and other topics...
i guess i can say that when Apple, Google and MS join hands in one trend, it would have a bright future.